# Restore dynamic form to its initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on legacy jQuery-powered project. There is a search (filter) form which is built dynamically while the user interacts with it. "Built dynamically" means that some HTML elements (`select`, `input`, `radio` buttons) are created and inserted into form on-the-fly by playing with existing selects. There already is functionality that lets the user erase all the elements created and existing from the start page load.

Now I have requirement to completely restore the form state to exactly as it was on page load. It can be easily implemented by cloning initial form state into a constant with `actual.parentNode.replaceChild(initial, actual)`. The problem is that I lose all the event handlers for the existing form elements. The form just stops being interactive.

Could someone suggest an approach to be used to implement the requirements above?

Comment: You'll need to show us some code.

Comment: change your form event handlers to delegated event handlers or rebind them after you restore the form

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a specific class to all the element that you create, then when you want to reset the form, you just use:

`$(".your_custom_class_here").remove()`

to delete all created elements

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the form using jquery :

```
 $( "#form" ).load(window.location.href + " #form" );
```

You should also change your event handlers to delegated ones, instead of using

```
$("#element").on("click", function() {...});
```

You should use :

```
$(document).on("click", "#element", function() {...});
```

So the new elements and the reloaded ones work with these event handlers.